# Get image info from header (width, height, etc) without opening it

Tags: c++, image

I have been using OpenCV to read and manage images. But now, given the image path, I want to QUICKLY store only the image path, width and height (I do not want to load the image buffer), for a wide range of image formats.

[OpenCV](http://answers.opencv.org/question/6234/get-the-image-size-without-actually-opening-it/) does not allow to do this without loading the whole image. I could implement image header parsers for a set of formats, but this might take a while.

Is there any library or so that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `ImageMagick` at the command line like this:

```
identify -ping image.png
image.png PNG 510x500 510x500+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.36KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Or, if you have lots of images to do in a single invocation, use it like this:

```
identify -ping -format "%f %w %h\n" *.png
a.png 500 500
image.png 510 500
n.png 500 510
s.png 510 500
sw.png 510 550
w.png 510 500
```

C/C++, Python and Perl bindings are also available. It is installed on most Linux distros, and available for OSX and Windows from [here](http://imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Comment: Thank you! But I was searching for a simpler alternative (cross platform), prefrably with no dependence on libaries.

Comment: @manatttta you're searching for a library (as per question) but no dependence on libraries? what does that even mean. You should probably clarify what is it exactly you want.