# Is there any way to get header information of an image using opencv and c++

Tags: c++, opencv

Header information such as extension, date of creation, height, width, device used to capture it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864283/get-image-info-from-header-width-height-etc-without-opening-it/30864373#30864373

Answer (score 2):

No.

The width and height are already given by the shape of the `Mat` you get when you open the file.

The other info is likely EXIF/IPTC data, and OpenCV doesn't expose it. You could use a different library such as [exiv2](https://www.exiv2.org) to access it.

Or you can use `popen()` to call [jhead](https://www.sentex.ca/~mwandel/jhead/), [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) or some similar command-line tool.